# A way to update Url with Angular Material Tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-router

Angular 6 using Angular Material, display a list, using tabs to go on item details "page".

[image: Route]

My route is simple:

```ts
{
    path: '', component: CurrenciesComponent
}
```

and I tried something like this:

```ts
{
    path: 'currencies',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: CurrenciesComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'currencies/:id', component: CurrenciesDetailComponent }
    ]
}
```

I searched to find a solution, but nothing to solve it. Maybe this is not possible using Material Tabs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the tabs pattern with routes, use the `mat-tab-nav-bar` and `mat-tab-link` directives. There is not a lot of documentation about this: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation.

Comment: When using what's in the documentation, the `<router-outlet>` is completely ignored and the whole page is redirected, losing the tabs. How can we fix that?

Comment: @NatoBoram start a new topic.